# ていい after potential form

Tags: grammar, meaning, potential-form, rhetorical-questions

I was listening to the song 命に嫌われている and came across the following lyrics:

> 寂しいなんて言葉でこの傷が**表せていい**ものか
>
> そんな意地ばかり抱え今日も一人ベッドに眠る

I don’t understand what ていい is doing here. An attempt at a direct translation would go something like “there’s no way it’s alright for one to be able to express their hurt by saying they’re lonely” but that sounds quite off to me. If it had been 表していい I would understand, but 表せていい? How does ていい work with potential forms?

(Lyrics taken from [this site](https://utaten.com/lyric/%E5%88%9D%E9%9F%B3%E3%83%9F%E3%82%AF/%E5%91%BD%E3%81%AB%E5%AB%8C%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%82%8B%E3%80%82/).)

Answer (score 2):

"lonely" should not be a sufficient word to express this hurt,
with such (trivial) prides I go to bed alone again today

IMHO, 表せていい　is "can be expressed" 
but with ものか it should not be able to be expressed
there for I translate "not a sufficient word to express"